# how to make a post require a manual approval by admin before getting displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a new rails developer and I have a rails app where I allow users to make a post while allowing them an option to check a checkbox. I want to be able to manually review all posts that are checked by users during their posting process. Right now everything is getting posted successfully but I want this review process in place for all checkmarked posts. What is the simplest and easiest way to put this review in place?

Here's what the post controller is right now

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Shared!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if the user checks the checkbox, the post needs to be reviewed, but is not visible until it has been reviewed and accepted? And if the checkbox is not checked, the post isn't shared at all?

Comment: @Zaid, yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

For this, you better keep data-type of "reviewed" field as "boolean" (in migration files).

For putting up check box in your view, check: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements

Also, note that IF YOU WANT to validate the presence of boolean field (where the real values are true and false), you can't use:

```
validate :field_name, :presence => true
```

this is due to the way Object#blank? handles boolean values. false.blank? # => true 
In this case, you can use:

```
validates :field_name, :allow_nil => true, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
```

You can omit ":allow_nil => true", from above validation statement if you are assigning false as default value to newly created posts (and that you would require to do before validations get triggered).

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not talking in perspective of RoR, but in general implementation*

In the database, add a field called 'Reviewed'. It holds a 'Y' or 'N'. default should be 'Y'.

Now, while saving or Updating the post make the check box flag a Y or N into this field and 
in the Model, Only query for posts with 'Reviewed' = 'Y'.

This way, if the user does not check the box, the default value is 'Y' and the posts shows up, but if the user checks the box, the value shall be 'N' and you develop a review interface (i hope you already did) where after review, you mark it to 'Y'.

This is as simple as it can get. If you need to add more information on who review it, when it is reviewed etc, you can add more DB fields to store that.

**Update**

I work on ColdFusion technology and we have CFWheels framework which is inspired by RoR.
Based on the experience, I suggest you to use the Form helpers.

Try this code

```
<%= check_box_tag(:post_reviewed) %>
<%= label_tag(:post_reviewed, "Review this post") %>
```

And for more details, read [check box tag in ruby on rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) and [check box form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)

Comment: I feel that I'm almost there. however, do you know how I can make it so that if a user checks the box, it makes the post reviewed = "N" and it doesn't show? (the code to make this association)

Comment: Set the checked value as 1 and unchecked as 0. Now, check the form values when they are posted. if it is checked, then save into your database 'N' else don't do anything. The default 'Y' would be already there and it would suffice.